# Decrypt password in application.properties WITHOUT jasypt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encryption

I have spring-boot 2.0 application has encrypted properties in application.properties as below

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.datasource.url=mysql_url
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=ENC:encrypted_password

spring.redis.host=111.1.1.1
spring.redis.port=18729
spring.redis.password=ENC:redis_encrypted_password
```

I have my own applications custom encryption and decryption mechanisam and do not want use jasypt lib.

Now I have extended PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and have below configuration

```
/**
 * Decrypt passwrods in properties if they are already decrypted.
 * If property starts with ENC: then only decrypt and return the property value
 *
 */
public class EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
        extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    /**
     * Decrypt password if its encrypted. If property starts with ENC: then its considered as encrypted.
     * @param originalValue
     * @return decrypted value if encrypted
     */
    @Override
    protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {
        if(originalValue!=null && originalValue.trim().startsWith("ENC:")) {
            String enc = originalValue.split("ENC:")[1];
            System.out.println(originalValue.split("ENC:")[1]);
            originalValue = MySecurityUtilsClass.decryptPassword(enc);
            System.out.println(" Decrypted passwrod "+ originalValue);
        }
        return originalValue;
    }
}
```

And configuration

```
@Configuration
public class AppBeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurerName() throws IOException {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer props = new EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        props.setSystemPropertiesMode( PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_NEVER );
        //add more properties as Required
        props.setLocation(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResource("classpath:/application.properties"));
        return props;
    }

}
```

Method convertPropertyValue is called but the properties are not decrypted and mysql connection fails with the wrong password.

Help will appriciated for the correct way of configuration without the use of jasypt lib

Comment: can someone please provide some help here

Comment: Does this line print the decrypted password? `System.out.println(" Decrypted passwrod "+ originalValue);` Why is your bean static?

Comment: yes it does print decrypted password

Answer (score 0):

Try running program after adding annotation `@Primary` after `@Bean` for `placeHolderConfigurerName()` method.